# Joomla - Admin login fails to work after latest CiviCRM update

Tags: upgrade, joomla, error-page

I have just upgraded CiviCRM to v5.65.1 in my Joomla site (v4.3.4). Now, since that update I can no longer login to my admin backend - I get the following error displayed:
0 Class "Civi\Core\Container" not found

I have backed up the database files using the function in PHPMyAdmin, but need to rebuild the CiviCRM installation. Looking at the FTP backend, a lot of the CiviCRM files are zero bytes.

How do I restore my installation?

Comment: I am still trying to get access to my Joomla admin backend to sort this issue out. Can ANYONE here help?

Comment: You could try deleting the files (perhaps, back them up first just in case, though not sure it'll be of any value), and FTP the appropriate directory/file trees from the unzipped CiviCRM download file into /administrator/components/com_civicrm and into /components/com_civicrm. Please make sure you reinstate backup copies of the /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm_settings.php and /components/com_civicrm/civicrm_settings.php files. The Civi upgrade always overrides them for some odd reason. If you don't have backup copies, you could update the new files manually.

Comment: See the comment I made yesterday for the solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on the Joomla forum and was told to set the enabled flag for the CiviCRM apps to zero within phpMyAdmin.

This did work and I was then able to apply the update that failed earlier to CiviCRM.

Maybe this is something that the developers should include in the documentation?

Comment: Checking I follow correctly: you tried to update (hopefully following https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/) but that resulted in zero-byte files and inability to log in.  You disabled CiviCRM then updated again and it worked?  I'm curious about those zero-byte files. Were you out of disk space?

Comment: No. I was not out of disk space. IONOS provide unlimited storage space. Previous CiviCRM updates have worked faultlessly.